# Implementing tool tips

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've reviewed the docs on Imagemapster's web site, as well as numerous posts here, but can't get the tooltips to work properly. I tried posting the HTML and JS on jsfiddle.com but was unable to get it to work properly, so here's a link to the sample map http://www.teenspanish.com/imagemap/. It's a very simple idea, once the map is functioning properly I can apply the appropriate code to the real project.

1) the hover effects work just fine, no concern there.

2) there is a div under the map that it intended to be hidden when the page loads, but it is visible. As soon as you move the mouse over one of the hotspots it is replaced with the appropriate text, and from that point on the map seems to function properly. So, there must be something missing or incorrect in the code that regulates the onMouseover and onMouseout effects.

3) is there any way to position the tooltips over the map (hotspots) itself, as most tooltips do? As it is, all the text appears inside a div under the map, but I'd prefer to have it positioned over the hotspots.

I have no problem with CSS, but have virtually no experience working with JS, so I don't really know where to start. This sample was created from various samples I'm come across since stumbling on Imagemapster. If somebody could review the code and let me know what's wrong it would be very much appreciated, as would any suggestions or links to helpful resources.

Here's my code:

```
var image = $('#map1'); 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#map1').mapster({ 
        singleSelect : true, 
        clickNavigate : false, 
        mapKey: 'color', 
        listKey: 'name', 
        fillColor: "ffffff", 
        fillOpacity : 0.5, 
        onMouseover: function (e) { 
            $('#myDiv').html(xref[e.key]); 
        }, 
        onMouseout: function (e) { 
            if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) { 
                $('#myDiv').html(''); 
            } 
        }, 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: When the mouse leaves a hot-spot, the contents of the div with the id `myDiv` are emptied. That is to say - the div is always visible on the page, it's just that it has zero size after a mouse-out on one of the map areas. Is there any reason you simply couldn't remove the text `This DIV should be hidden until you hover over one of the hot spots.` from the page? This would put the page in a state initially that is identical to the one it's in after a mouseout, unless I'm missing something. :)

Comment: Hi Enhzflep, no you're not missing something, I'm missing something:) What can I say,Ajax, jQuerty, CSS, PHP, etc., sometimes it gets so overwhelming your brain just shuts down. I've got that part working right now, thanks for your help. http://www.teenspanish.com/imagemap/.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the div holding the tooltip according to the mouse position:

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

JS:

```
onMouseover: function (args) {
    var container = $("#myDiv"),
        event = args.e;
    container.html(xref[args.key]).show();
    container.css({
        "top": event.clientY,
        "left": event.clientX
    });
},
onMouseout: function (args) {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
}
```

Don't forget to remove the comma after the `onMouseout`.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I have added the code you suggested but for some reason the map stopped functioning. When I added the new code Dreamweaver highlighted a coding error on line 49, which is odd because I never changed that code. Here's a link to the map functioning correctly without the code changes, http://teenspanish.com/imagemap/ , and here's a link with the code changes http://teenspanish.com/imagemap/index2.html. If you would be so kind as to take a look, perhaps you can find an error in the coding. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Mark Please post the code in the question as this is a requirement on SO. It takes a bit longer for me to go to your page and debug your code there. If you can create a jsfiddle sample that will help out as well.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I can't get the jsfiddle to work properly, so here is the JS

Comment: var image = $('#map1');

$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $('#map1').mapster({
 singleSelect : true,
 clickNavigate : false,
     mapKey: 'color',
  listKey: 'name',
 fillColor: "ffffff",
 fillOpacity : 0.5,
       onMouseover: function (e) {
      
            $('#myDiv').html(xref[e.key]);
   
        },
  onMouseout: function (e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
             $('#myDiv').html('');
    }
        },
});
});

Comment: @Mark Remove the comma after the onMouseout event handler.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, there is only one comma in the onMouseout area, and I eliminated it, but it still won't' work. As well, Dreamweaver shows the same error on line 49. At the very bottom of the code there are two two double brackets, the error message is showing on the first one, not the last one.

Comment: @Mark I don't know what's on line 49, but the code that you posted is fine, except for the comma after the last object which you've removed.

Comment: OK Konstantin, thanks so much for all your help, it is very much appreciated. I'll do the best I can, best of luck.